# Check contents of div to apply a particular ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xslt

I'm using XSLTs to basically take some basic HTML and implant some CSS so that the resulting file is the original file + the embedded CSS as one single self contained file. No problems so far, all works fine.

However.

Some of my input documents dont have properly formatted div ids, so the CSS I embedded isnt picking up on those items (the input docs come from 4 different providers who all like to do things separately, yay!).

Is there any way (js?jquery?) that I can check the text contents of the div for a particular word, and then assign an ID to the div its in? For example, a div should have the ID "Allergies", but if it doesnt, I need to check the div text to look for the word "Allergy", and then assign "Allergies" as the div Id.

Sounds a bit odd I know, but if its possible it would greatly help my ability to get the output documents all conforming to one layout and style.

This is to be displayed on Blackberrys/WinPhones, so the restrictions of those should be taken into account.

Many thanks,

Christian

Answer (score 0):

Why not write code in xslt itself to generate id

```
<xsl:if test="contains(value, 'Allergy')">
   <xsl:attribute name="id">
      Allergies
   </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

Using jQuery, you need plugin http://plugins.learningjquery.com/textchildren/

```
$(content).("div").each( function(index) {
   if($(this).textChildren().contains("Allergy")){
      $(this).addClass("Allergies");
   }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can I use one or the other of these or do they go together? In the first example, where would I put this block of code?

Comment: You can use either one, first one i will recommend. You can use this code in XSLT while looping through your entity, like medicine or disease, means the block u want to create for. May be detailed XSL and XSLT will help.